pass recent history to LLM with current prompt
I have the azure openai code below that I am running in python 3.10.  In the bot_response function I am passing a query in from the user and getting a response from the LLM.  I would like to modify the code so that when being prompted the LLM will get the full history of the last three queries from the user and responses from the LLM.  I would like to modify the code so the LLM is aware of the recent chat history between the user and the LLM.  I know with lanchain agents there's a memory buffer option that achieves something similar.  Is there anything like that for azure openai chat completion?  Or Can anyone suggest how to do this?
code:
from openai import AzureOpenAI

def bot_response(query):
    client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=xxxx,
    azure_deployment=xxxxx,
    azure_endpoint=xxxxx,
    api_version=xxxx
    )


    chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
    {
    "role":"system",
    "content":("Instructions:\n"
    "do stuff\n"
    )
    },
    {
    "role":"user",
    "content":query,
    }
    ],
    model="gpt-4",
    response_format={"type":"json_object"}
    )
    return chat_completion.choices[0].message.content


I think this is highly dependent on which LLM you're using. If I remember the OpenAI API, you can create a session which remembers up to x amount of tokens of history for better context based responses.

This question is similar to: How to maintain context with OpenAI gpt-3.5-turbo API?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can just have a chat history array and when prompted a new chat, update the array with input and output. Something like this might work
from openai import AzureOpenAI

history = []

def bot_response(query):
    client = AzureOpenAI(
        api_key="xxxx",
        azure_deployment="xxxxx",
        azure_endpoint="xxxxx",
        api_version="xxxx"
    )

history.append({"role": "user", "content": query})
recent_history = history[-7:]

system_message = {
    "role": "system",
    "content": (
        "Instructions:\n"
        "do stuff\n"
    )
}

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[system_message] + recent_history,
    model="gpt-4",
    response_format={"type": "json_object"}
)

bot_reply = chat_completion.choices[0].message.content
history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": bot_reply})

return bot_reply

